# can I use Touchables like TouchableWithoutFeedback instead of using button for this.props.navigation.navigate in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')} > 
    { 
        this.props.type!=='1' ? <Icon2 name="chevron-with-circle-left" size={28}/> 
                              : <Icon name='chevron-left' style={{ color: "#16527e" }} size={35}/>
    }
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

This code is showing an error that this.props.navigation.navigate is not an object . Is that necessary to use button for navigation for using this.props.navigation.navigate? can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. You can use whatever function for your onPress. I think that the problem is your navigation object.. is it undefined?

Try with this code and read what it's logged:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={()=> console.log("Navigation is :", this.props.navigation}> 
              { this.props.type!=='1'?
                <Icon2 name="chevron-with-circle-left" size={28}/> 
                : <Icon name='chevron-left' style={{ color: "#16527e" }} 
                  size={35}/>
              }
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Ensure that navigation contains the "navigate" function and, if it's necessary, log even "this.props.navigation.navigate".

At the end ensure that react-navigation is configured properly.

Something more: if you are trying to use navigation inside a presentational component make sure that navigation is an object inside the container component and pass navigation down as a prop. If react-navigation opens the page XYZ ensure that navigation.navigate works in XYZ and pass it to other components as a prop.
If XYZ opens from react-navigation routing it should have this.props.navigation. XYZ renders ABC. XYZ should pass this.props.navigation to ABC as a prop:

```
<ABC navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>
```